# Table with key is date and serial number

Tags: mysql, sql, max

thank you in advance for your help.

I have an SQL table which looks like this.

[image]

date and serial number are a composite key together. Meaning there cannot be a tuple with the same date and the same serial_number. Now, I want to get the most recent date (transaction) per serial_number. How can I do this? This is what i tried but it gives me some duplicates.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`t1`.date,'%m-%d-%y') as date  , `t1`.serial_number
FROM table1 `t1`
WHERE date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table1 GROUP BY serial_number)
order by `t1`.date desc, `t1`.serial_number asc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need correlated subquery not only subquery :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.date,'%m-%d-%y') as date, t.serial_number
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.date = (SELECT MAX(t1.date) 
                FROM table1 t1 
                WHERE t1.serial_number = t.serial_number
               )
order by t.date desc, t.serial_number asc;
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution is the most similar to what I tried, and it is not as verbose as scaisEdge answer so I am accepting it as the correct answer. Thank you both for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a inner join on max_date for serial_number

```
> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`t1`.date,'%m-%d-%y') as date  
>     , `t1`.serial_number FROM `table` `t1` INNER JOIN (
>     SELECT serial_number, MAX( DATE_FORMAT(`T`.date,'%m-%d-%y')) max_date 
>     FROM `table` T
>     GROUP BY serial_number ) T ON T.serial_number = `t1`.serial_number AND T.max_date  = DATE_FORMAT(`t1`.date,'%m-%d-%y')
> 
> order by `t1`.date desc, `t1`.serial_number asc;
```

Comment: Fixed some minor syntax mistakes on this solution. Works well! Thank you for your help